# Is there a way to get filter out of Arrow::Array and some predicate?

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

Assume that I have an `Arrow::Array` (or `Dataframe` or `ChunkedArray`, not important) and I have some predicate. I want to compute a new `Arrow::BooleanArray` which just stores result of this predicate applied to each of the array element.

My case is that I have two sorted arrays of `date32` and I want to return a mask which tells me if the value of the first array is present in the second. Like the following:

```
std::shared_ptr<arrow::BooleanArray> getDatesMask(
    const std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>& lhs,
    const std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>& lhs) 
{
   // some pseudo code how this could work
   // for date in lhs:
   //     res.Append(date in rhs);
   // return res;
}
```

Comment: Not an exact match, but would set_difference in algorithm be useful?

Comment: [set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference).  Note there is also `std::set_intersection`, and other `std::set_` related algorithm functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you need the `is_in` compute function:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<arrow::BooleanArray> getDatesMask(
    const std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>& haystack,
    const std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>& needles)
{
  arrow::Datum mask = arrow::compute::IsIn(haystack, needles).ValueOrDie();
  return std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::BooleanArray>(mask.make_array());
}
```

Documentation of `is_in` (and other compute functions) at: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/compute.html#containment-tests

Comment: This works the only comment is that one need to add `#include <arrow/compute/api_scalar.h>`